# Swift - Round Button

Tags: ios, swift, button, uikit-dynamics

I want to create several round buttons in swift, with collision detection and gravity acting on them. But whenever I do so, during collision they acts as a square, (I've tried adding image to button or by creating it through code but the result remains the same), so can anyone help as I want to create round buttons that acts like round shape whenever they collide or fall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **OBShapedButton**

this one is third party class available for different shape type buttons and button created with this class acts as shape of image you have given to button.

https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton

To use this in storyboard or xib file just give Custom Class as `OBShapedButton` to `UIButton`.

**or programmatically**

```
obj_OBShapedButton = [OBShapedButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[obj_OBShapedButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 160,161)];

[obj_OBShapedButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[obj_OBShapedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Buton_action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:obj_OBShapedButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

To actually answer the original question:

Since the release of iOS 9 you can now change the collision shape to be circular (or any other shape).

In your `UIButton` subclass you can add this:

```
- (UIDynamicItemCollisionBoundsType)collisionBoundsType
{
    return UIDynamicItemCollisionBoundsTypeEllipse;
}
```

This will set the collision bounds to be a circle instead of the default rectangle.

Answer (score -1):

If there is collision and gravity, use SpriteKit instead. Create any shape there as SKNode would work.

Comment: I am not that much familiar with SpriteKit thatswhy I was avoiding it. Can I do the same in ViewController ??

Comment: @AmanKumar I just don't understand... SpriteKit is designed as Physics Engine that handles collision, gravitation and everything. Why not just learn a little bit the easiest tool, instead of UIKit.  It's like, there is a free airplane can take you from US to China, but you are asking people how to build a wooden boat and sail across the Pacific ocean.